# Is hierarchical regression appropriate for running a regression using multilevel dependent variable?

Tags: mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

I have a paper submitted to a journal and one of the reviewers suggested me to conduct a hierarchical logistic regression. I know how to conduct multilevel regression analysis by clustering the data at different levels. Like for example a sample of students can be clustered by classrooms, and then by schools etc. But, what the reviewer asked is clustering using the dependent variable. 
Is any one out there who could help by giving some clue or recommending any reading materials.

Comment: Can you please give more details in general? The clustering is always done on the dependant variable using the independent variable information... In your example say you care about the students' grade, the clustering is based on the students classrooom, school, county, etc. Did you mean to say independent? I mean someone might want to add some arbitrary categories based on the dependent variable (say below, within or above a particular interval) but this seems rather ad-hoc (and very probably wrong).

Comment: To give a bit of detail. For example my dependent variable is students' total score ( composed of maths, English and aptitude results) and the independent variables are gender, income etc. my question is ...is that possible to run a hierarchical regression like first level regression for maths, then English and last stage for aptitude test scores?

Comment: Ah... :) OK... Isn't there a deterministic formula that corresponds to the final grade though? eg. $\text{Score}_\text{Total} = \alpha_1 \text{Score}_\text{Maths} + ... + \alpha_p \text{Score}_\text{English}$. I suspect they want to suggest that maybe some schools are better than other in certain subjects that carry more influence... You could break the model in different subject-specific sub-models and then combine them back but that feels rather odd...

Comment: Ah... :) OK... Isn't there a deterministic formula that corresponds to the final grade though? eg. $\text{Score}_\text{Total} = \alpha_1 \text{Score}_\text{Maths} + ... + \alpha_p \text{Score}_\text{English}$. I suspect they want to suggest that maybe some schools are better than other in certain subjects that carry more influence... You could break the model in different subject-specific sub-models and then combine them back but that feels rather odd...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My original model is Total score = f(student gender, income, etc). I understand, I can run a sub-models regression for Maths, English and Aptitude. But, I suppose that is not a hierarchical regression. What I am suggested to do is run a regression on maths then English then aptitude using a hierarchical regression instead of running a sub-model. I am wondering if that is possible.

Comment: Why do you refer to logistic regression?  That is not used when the outcome is a score measured on a fine-grained scale.

Comment: (Oh, yes +1 to @ronaldo2's comment I focused on the "clustering part".) BTW, If the outcome is some percentage the reviewer might be crack-pot enough to assume it is a probability. This isn't the case is it? On second thought, asking for ordinal regression would be much more reasonable.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Yes the dependent variable is in percentage. I am also surprised why he/she suggested for hierarchical logistic regression.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you can have maths, English and aptitude outcomes at different levels of a hierarchical model.

If you want to separate the scores and have them as different outcomes in one model then you could use multivariate multiple regression or a structural equation model. Edit: I have just come across the [`ASReml`](http://www.r-bloggers.com/multivariate-linear-mixed-models-livin%E2%80%99-la-vida-loca/) package which allows for multiple response variables in a mixed/hierarchical model, so that could be a good option

I suspect the reviewer is asking for a hierarchical model with students at one level, clustered in (say) classrooms, or schools, at higher levels. However, why they suggest a *logistic* model makes no sense to me.

Comment: I am not sure this is advice is very accurate. A hierarchical model at student level with the response variable being the composite test score would have a different random effects level per measurement. (I like your avatar by the way, personal hero of mine that guy...)

Comment: One could "theoretically" reformulate the model so he aggregates the individual lesson scores into one response vector. Then he would be able to use `student` as a random effect but he would have to also use an indicator variable for each specific `subject`-specific score to model the mean response. This could probably work but you would likely bleed out some serious degrees of freedom from the model.

Comment: @usεr11852 If the student is a random effect / cluster , then what is clustered within each student ? If the 3 scores per student are aggregated into one then there would be only 1 measurement per student in the model and hence no clustering.

Comment: @usεr11852 glad you like it !

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am saying too. The idea of clustering within student seems implausible unless you change the response variable to be the aggregate vector of the subject-specific scores. The way  the post is written doesn't really clear that up because you mention the word *model* for different models.

Comment: @usεr11852  maybe my answer isn't clear. Which part is the problem for you ? The last paragraph ? This would obviously only apply if there were actual hierarchies in the data such as classrooms or schools.  The 2nd paragraph suggests an SEM model with multiple outcomes, while the 1st says that you can't have multiple outcomes in a hierarchical model and if you aggregate them then there won't be any clustering anyway.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I understand how to run a a hierarchical regression by clustering the student scores by classroom, school and location etc.  My concern is whether hierarchical regression is  appropriate to run a regression by dividing the dependent variables into different levels.

Comment: continued....My dependent variable is student score which is an aggregate score( weighted score) of the three subjects (Maths, English and Aptitude). I am not quite sure if multilevel regression is appropriate as @Robert Long suggested. To make it clear, what I am suggested is running a single model using hierarchical regression instead of running a regression for the aggregate score and then a sub-model for each subject. Of course it could not be a logistic regression as my dependent variable is a percentage not "0" and "1".

Comment: @user120062 OK, but do you have students clustered within schools, class or similar ? ? You can't divide the DV into different "levels", in the sense of  levels in a hierarchical/mixed/multilevel model.  If you want to run such a model then you need to have a single DV, with most software that I am aware of. The only exception I know is `asreml` which I have just come across but have never used.

Comment: Yeah, It was the bit connecting from the separate regressions to the hierarchical model. Your comment made it clear. (+1). @user120062: `MCMCglmm` allows for multiple responses too if you are interested in MCMCing this model out.